# How is the fate of endosperm decided?

Tags: botany, embryology

I was studying about the post-fertilization events in angiosperms and I came to know that in most dicotyledons, the endosperm is completely consumed and in most monocotyledons, the endosperm is not consumed completely. Why does this happen? Does it have anything to do with the suspensor cells? Does it depend on how much the suspensor cells push the developing embryo into the endosperm? Or, does it depend on something else?